# Change Background Color of a Button in an Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to change the background color of a button when I click it. My goal is that the color should be changed for 5 seconds and then change again to another color.

The original color of the button is yellow.

Here is a part of the code I have tried:

```
public void click(View view){
  myTestButton = (Button)view;
  myTestButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  //*Wait lines;*
  myTestButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

The button changes color to red but never to blue. I suspect that the view does not refresh until later. I want the button to be refreshed before the wait lines.
I've also tried `myTestButton.invalidate()` but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for some great tips on this!!

Comment: Part of the issue is that the view will refresh on the same thread as the one you are running on. So it doesn't get a chance to update until the method ends, at which time the button is now red.

Answer (score 2):

What are you using in your "wait lines"? I guess there is a problem there, as you **may not cause your UI thread to sleep there, and this method (onClick) IS called by your UI thread.**

I suggest you to use the method `View.postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMills` to do that.
Example:

```
myTestButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myTestButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Note that you muest declare `myTestButton` as `final` in your onClick method.

Comment: No problem :) If it solved the problem, mark it as "accepted" so this question will be marked as "solved".