# Changing color of a button according to boolean

Tags: java, android, button, boolean

Okey so I have created some booleans and according to them I would like to set color of a button.
So lets say I have

```
boolean test1 = true;
boolean test2 = false;
```

True would be green and false would be red.
And now I would like my program to set the colors to buttons according to booleans.

```
package com.example.kamil.tmpsadmin;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 String  button1nazwa = "Kamil", button1register = "SJZ-RG78",
         button2nazwa = "Daniel", button2register = "SJZ-7782",
         button3nazwa = "Kajetan", button3register = "SJZ-6669",
         button4nazwa = "Szymon", button4register = "SJZ-GRA3",
         button5nazwa = "Bartek", button5register = "SJZ-MET2",
         button6nazwa = "Paweeł", button6register = "SJZ-KOZAK";
 Boolean button1dostepnosc = true, button2dostepnosc = true, button3dostepnosc = false, button4dostepnosc = false, button5dostepnosc = false, button6dostepnosc = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(button1nazwa + "\n" + button1register + "\n");
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(button2nazwa + "\n" + button2register + "\n");
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView3.setText(button3nazwa + "\n" + button3register + "\n");
    TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView4.setText(button4nazwa + "\n" + button4register + "\n");
    TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    textView5.setText(button5nazwa + "\n" + button5register + "\n");
    TextView textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    textView6.setText(button6nazwa + "\n" + button6register + "\n");
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Zmiana.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, and where is the problem? What's your actual question? Can you show us your code with the buttons? I mean you need buttons and some `changeColor` method and then a simple `if` statement, nothing fancy.

Comment: Well I really have no idea how should I do it. Like do I put an if statement in onCreate in my mainactivity?
EDIT : Oh thats what I thought, I still really dont know how should I do it :/

Comment: Please show us your code. I don't even know the buttons we are talking about.

Comment: I edited the post showing my code.

Comment: Nice. See, I thought you are talking about swing buttons. But its android stuff instead. Make sure to use the right tags (android in this case) or you get the wrong experts to your question. Now, with the tag, you get all the android experts.

Comment: Ah okay now I will know, thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with android but code could look like `if(condition) { button.setColor(Color.GREEN); } else { button.setColor(Color.RED); }` or something like that. You will need to research how to change android button colors and how those methods are then called.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking about, and I should put that into onCreate so it does that everytime I open the app and in condition I would put the if boolean1=true

Comment: Also see [Change Background Color of a Button in an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957494/change-background-color-of-a-button-in-an-android-application) and other results of a simple google query: [java android button change color](https://www.google.de/search?q=java%20android%20button%20change%20color)

Comment: Yeah, but note that you don't need to compare against `true`. Something like `if (variable == true)` is the same as just `if (variable)` since the variable already is a `boolean`. I mean, if `variable` is set to `true` you have `true == true` which resolves to `true`, and if it was `false` you would have `false == true` which resolves to `false`. So you could just have used `variable` from the beginning without comparing it to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with a if-then-else-statement:

```
if (test1) {
    //set button1 color to green
} else {
   //set button1 color to red
}

if (test2) {
   //set button2 color to green
} else {
   //set button2 color to red
}
```

This would be a solution with arrays. Notice that all values in `colorBool` are false per default.

```
int count = 10; //leads to ten buttons
boolean[] colorBool = new boolean[count];
Button[] buttons = new Button[count];

for (int i = 0; i < colorBool.length; i++) {
    if (colorBool[i]) {
        buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I see, that would work great with like few buttons, but what about if I have like 20 of them? Should I do an i statement for every of them or is there any quicker way?

Comment: You can put the booleans into an array and the buttons in another array. Then you can loop through the arrays.

Comment: Oh, arrays hmm. Do you have any good tutorial how to use them? Everything I research seems pretty advanced for me

Comment: @KamilCiesielski Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) helps.

Comment: @KamilCiesielski Feel free to ask if you have any questions regarding arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check this:

```
if(test1 == true)
{
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
if(test2 == true)
{
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```